# setState to a state located in App.js from another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-hooks, axios

I have a file called `api.js` where I have my axios configs stored. I'm currently using axios and I want to log the user out if any axios request receives a response with a 401 status code. Now my problem is that how can I clear the states in App.js from the api.js file?

```
/* api.js */
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create();

api.interceptors.request.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      /* clear all states in App.js */
      console.log("unauthenticated");
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

  /* states in App.js */
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [shifts, setShifts] = useState([]);
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using `useState` hook manage states in the `App` component. Its not really the way for you to directly manipulate the state of the react component outside of that component.

To fix it, i would suggest maybe using [Context API](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context). This way you can consume it where its needed -  in your case the api.js file.

**Here is an code example usage**: AuthContext.js

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [shifts, setShifts] = useState([]);
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);

  const logout = () => {
    setUser(null);
    setShifts([]);
    setJobs([]);
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, shifts, jobs, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**At the App level - add the context**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { AuthProvider } from './AuthContext';

    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <AuthProvider>
          <App />
        </AuthProvider>
      </React.StrictMode>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

**and finally edit your api.js file with changes as such**:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from './AuthContext';

const api = axios.create();

api.interceptors.request.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  async (error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      const { logout } = useContext(AuthContext);
      logout();
      console.log("unauthenticated");
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```